# echo raw javascript from Yii Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, controller

Any one know how to echo raw javascript from controller. I need to use a window open on specific case after a ajax request, As for specific ajax cases url can have different parameters. And I managed it in one private method on Controller Side. So all ajax requests method call this private method and in case of condition met, Open a window through it. 
I tried like

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('$url', '_parent', '')</script>";
```

But look like Yii filtered html for safety.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this function:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myscript', "window.open(" . $url . ", '_parent', '')");
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes to the `$url` parameter, `"window.open('" . $url . "', '_parent', '')" should do the job :)

Comment: Is registerScript works in ajax request ? As I do not see any thing happening. I did check with firebug but not response return at all.

Comment: Do you render something? As far as I know it includes the registered script when some view is being rendered. Why don't you register this script when success callback is executed? Return the url with ajax request and call window.open in success callback

Comment: @Mikhel If that is only option I have, then I need to do it. But I prefer the way to handle code from very same location. Not every instance of controller actions and related ajax code callbacks.

Comment: Code should look a lot cleaner if you just return url and call the window.open in success callback. You can always call render function with blank layout to echo the script you registered.